# Convert struct to *interface{}

Tags: go

I'm using `checkr/goflagr`, specifically trying to build an [EvalContext](https://github.com/checkr/goflagr/blob/master/docs/EvalContext.md) and fill in the EntityContext field (some content removed below for the sake of brevity)

```golang
type EvalContext struct {

    EntityContext *interface{} `json:"entityContext,omitempty"`
    // flagID
    FlagID int64 `json:"flagID,omitempty"`

}
```

This code is generated by SwaggerGen, and I'm not sure how I can send in a struct to this function without having some awful workaround.

My intuition said I should be able to just pass the address of an instance of a struct, e.g.

```golang
    type entityContext struct {
        Environment string `json:"environment"`
    }

    entityContextImpl := entityContext{Environment:"prod"}

    eval_ctx := goflagr.EvalContext{
        FlagID: int64(19),
        EntityContext: &entityContextImpl,
    }
```

But this fails with

```
cannot use &entityContextImpl (type *entityContext) as type *interface {} in field value:
    *interface {} is pointer to interface, not interface
```

I've gotten it to work with the following workaround:

```golang
func convertToStarInterface(i interface{}) *interface{} {
    return &i
}

func myFunc() {
    type entityContext struct {
        Environment string `json:"environment"`
    }

    entityContextImpl := entityContext{Environment:"prod"}

    ec := goflagr.EvalContext{
        FlagID: int64(18),
        EntityContext: convertToStarInterface(entityContextImpl),
    }
}
```

But it feels like there must be a way around having to use this converter function

Comment: `var entityContextImpl interface{} = entityContext{Environment:"prod"}`, the rest would work unchanged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `*interface{}` is as ugly as it can get. It is perfectly possible to implement `omitempty` with an interface{}, because an `interface{}` can be nil. You should consider submitting a bug for this. Anyhow...

If you need to pass an `*interface{}`, you can do it:

```
var i interface{}
i=someStruct{}
ctx.EntityContext=&i
```

Your function works as well, however, it is not necessarily efficient or easier on the eye.

Comment: Yeah, the `EntityContext` field isn't required, it's just ugly since it's a `*interface{}`. This works well, @zerkms's comment as well works which is basically the same thing but in-lining the var declaration and assignment, which to me looks a lot better on the eyes